# sorting an array with special characters (german Umlaute) in GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm working on a GWT 2.6.1 project receiving data from a MySQL database.

All working fine but I have a problem with the öäüÖÄÜß (special chars) from the German language.

```
public void onSuccess(RPCObjectStringArray result) {
    String[] resultArray = result.getStringarray();
    Arrays.sort(resultArray,new ComparenoCaseUmlaut());
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}

public class ComparenoCaseUmlaut implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);    
        collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY); // non case sensitive                 
        return collator.compare(arg0,arg1);
    }

}
```

But this can't work while GWT doesn't support the collator lib.

So - I tried this (to make it easy to follow - I've changed the resultArray to an example):

```
String[] resultArray = { "Abc", "öbc", "BBC", "the", "abd", "X"};

public class ComparenoCaseUmlaut implements Comparator<String> {

@Override
public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {

    String string0 = arg0.toLowerCase();
    String string1 = arg1.toLowerCase();
    string0.replace("ä", "a");
    string0.replace("ö", "o");
    string0.replace("ü", "u");
    string0.replace("ß", "s");
    string1.replace("ä", "a");
    string1.replace("ö", "o");
    string1.replace("ü", "u");
    string1.replace("ß", "s");
    return string0.compareTo(string1);
}
```

The result:
 "Abc"
 "abd"
 "BBC"
 "the"
 "X"
 "öbc"

I've debugged that the .replace function doesn't act as expected. It can't replace the "ö" char - cause he couldn't find it. A compare with "==" the same...

I've changed the charset in my eclipse project to UTF-8 - nothing changed.

I'm new to java (for about a couple of months and also to GWT but an oldie in programming), so please give me some details - or a link... I could study by myself and bring the result back here. But at the moment I don't know were I have to begin....

I read something about plugins for eclipse and the GWT Internationalization but it sounds too high to understand. Otherwise I would learn it - but would it be helpfully?

Comment: `string.replace` returns a new string and does not modify in-place.

Comment: OK - you're so right :) That's my fault. Now my test example is fully working :) But i think i still have a problem with my MYSQL data ... so i check it out and be back in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - i've tested again with Marvins hint - it's working :) Very silly fault...

Before i changed my project to UTF-8, i tried it the correct way. But since i changed to the UTF-8 charset i doesn't tried it again, so i ran into this faulty code because i want to demonstrate a fault were nothing is :)

I've changed it...

```
public class ComparenoCaseUmlaut implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        String string0 = arg0.toLowerCase();
        String string1 = arg1.toLowerCase();
        string0 = string0.replace("ä", "a");
        string0 = string0.replace("ö", "o");
        string0 = string0.replace("ü", "u");
        string0 = string0.replace("ß", "s");
        string1 = string1.replace("ä", "a");
        string1 = string1.replace("ö", "o");
        string1 = string1.replace("ü", "u");
        string1 = string1.replace("ß", "s");
        return string0.compareTo(string1);  
    }

}
```

Something creepy with case sensitive in my result array ... but it's too late to figure it out for now...

Comment: If you want to compare ignoring case you could always change your last line to `string0.compareToIgnoreCase(string1);`

Comment: @JavaDevil: But then he would have to replace upper case and lower case variants of the characters, wouldn't he?

Comment: @Marvin He would have to do that if he wanted case sensitive sorting

Comment: @JavaDevil: He already made both strings lower case. So `compareToIgnoreCase` would only make sense if he did not call `toLowerCase`. But then `string.replace("ä")` won't replace `"Ä"`.

Comment: @Marvin Oh yup you are correct, didn't see those lines before. However that would have to have be done for a case sensitive comparison anyway.

Comment: @All all ok for now - the case sensitive error i meant - it was "\r\nIveco" -> should be "Iveco"... scary what to find in a database :)